# How to determine the number of digits needed to represent a number in different bases?

Tags: functions

I am not a mathematician, but I do some computer programming and I am trying to find a solution to a fairly simple problem.

Is there any known formula/equation/function for *mathematically* determining the number of display digits (aka "places") that will be required when converting one number between two different number bases?

Example: Let us use the number 65535 (base 10) set as the variable N.

- N base 10 requires 5 decimal digits (N10 = 65535)
- N base 2 requires 16 binary digits (N02 = 1111111111111111)
- N base 16 requires 4 hexadecimal digits (N16 = FFFF)

I want to feed N base 10 (N10) and another base into a formula or subroutine of some sort which returns a single number. Using the above example it might look something like this:

- function(65535,2) returns 16
- function(65535,16) returns 4

I want to explore some fairly large numbers in several different number bases and I am hoping this can be done as pure math, even if it requires multiple steps, rather than some sort of indexed table that would have to be created for each base.

- Example: function(1222333444555,99) = ???

PS: Feel free to add any other appropriate tags since I am not sure what else would be right for this question.

Comment: Hint: logarithms

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, there is a way: $$f(n, \text{base}) = \log_{\text{base}} (n) + 1\text{.}$$

After you compute the value of $f(n,b)$, you have to use *floor* function to get the right integer value.

Explanation:

- for numbers $b^k$, you need $k + 1$ places (digit $1$, followed by $k$ digits $0$)
- for numbers $b^k -1$, you need $k$ places ($k$ digits $(b - 1)$, e.g., $99999$ for $b = 10$)
- for numbers $n$ and $m$, such that $n\geq m$, then the number of places for $n$ is greater or equal to the number of places for $m$.

Hence, for all $b^{k - 1} \leq n \leq b^{k}-1$, you need $k$ places. The formula is just a fancy way to say this.

Comment: DOH!  I've been away from basic algebra too long! Put in the exponential form the equation is base^X = n, right ?

Comment: Ok I am a little confused by the explanation. You say "if n >= m" but do not explain what **m** is and never use it elsewhere. The rest I understand fine.

Comment: @O.M.Y. It should be clear now :)

Comment: Its is, Thanks Antoine.

Answer (score 0):

Explaining without logarithms, if $b^r\le n < b^{r+1}$, $n $ requires *exactly* $r$ digits in base $b$.

Comment: @Antoine: Oops! Thanks for pointing the typo!

Comment: If $b^r\le n < b^{r+1}$  then  $n $ requires exactly $r+1$ digits in base $b$.